# Delay video after clicking play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video

I have a div that has a full width video with position:absolute, that plays when clicking an image, and some text on top of the video.

What I want is when I click the play button for the text on top to fade out and after the text fades out, for the video to fade in and as well when I click the pause button for the video to fade out and after for the text to fade in.

I achieved something close to what I want but for some reason I cannot delay the video fadein the first time I click the play button. After the second click it seems to work fine.

Here is my code:

```
`<video preload="none" id="myVideo" width="100%" >
<source src="wp-content/themes/quill/images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
} 
</script>

<script>
    $("#play").click(function(){
        $("#pause").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#myVideo").delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
        $("#play").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".toph1").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".toph2").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".introduction").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".howitworks").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".logo").fadeOut(1000);
    });
</script>

<script>
    $("#pause").click(function(){
        $("#play").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".toph1").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".toph2").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".introduction").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".howitworks").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".logo").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#pause").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#myVideo").fadeOut(0);
    });
</script>`
```

I added the scripts at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a delay, try to use timeout function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // do here..
}, 750)
```

Comment: I did this: setTimeout(function playVid() { vid.play(); }, 2000) but now the video starts to play on it's own after 2 seconds.

Comment: The correct line was: function playVid() { setTimeout(function(){ vid.play(); , 750);}  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Fadeout has another optional parameter that can be passed for an on complete function:

```
  $( "#div" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {vid.play();}, 750)
  });
```

the function in the above call will only be triggered once the fadeout animation has completed. You will need to change #div to the correct ID.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete

Comment: Same problem as the answer bellow: the video has a timeout but after that it starts playing on his own

Comment: so you don't want the video to play, but rather just fade in when the object fades out? if so, replace the settimeout with this: `$("#myVideo").delay(1500).fadeIn(2000)`

Comment: That line already exists in: $("#play").click(function(){} and it works but only after the second click on the play button. The first time I click it, it appears instantly

Comment: I wrote the code wrong it works with just: function playVid() { setTimeout(function(){ vid.play(); }, 750);}